# Tensorflow, restore variables in a specific device

Tags: tensorflow

Maybe my question is a bit naive, but I really didn't find anything in the tensorflow documentation.

I have a trained tensorflow model where the variables of it was placed in the GPU. Now I would like to restore this model and test it using the CPU.

If I do this via 'tf.train.Saver.restore` as in the example:

 `saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph("/tmp/graph.meta")
 saver.restore(session, "/tmp/model.ckp")`

I have the following excpetion:

`InvalidArgumentError: Cannot assign a device to node 'b_fc8/b_fc8/Adam_1': Could not satisfy explicit device specification '/device:GPU:0' because no devices matching that specification are registered in this process; available devices: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0`

How can I make restore these variables in the `CPU`?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Use `clear_devices` flag, ie

```
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph("/tmp/graph.meta", clear_devices=True)
```

Comment: Thanks,
Actually this resource is available from the version `0.11`.
I'm using the 0.10.

Comment: @TiagoFreitasPereira, Then you can load GraphDef, iterate over nodes, clear field "device" and then import this GraphDef into your graph

Comment: also, you can open `graph.pbtxt` in a text editor, and remove every line starting with `device: `

Answer (score 1):

I'm using tensorflow 0.12 and `clear_devices=True` and `tf.device('/cpu:0')` was not working with me (saver.restore was still trying to assign variables to /gpu:0).

I really needed to force everything to /cpu:0 since I was loading several models which wouldn't fit in GPU memory anyways. Here are two alternatives to force everything to /cpu:0

1. Set `os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES']=''`
2. Use the device_count of ConfigProto like `tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(device_count={"GPU": 0, "CPU": 1}))`