# Restore tf-Model for CPU saved under GPU

Tags: tensorflow

I saved a model (tf version 0.12), trained on a machine with GPU. Now I need to restore it on a machine that only uses the CPU. I don't have access to the GPU-machine as I am on travel and would have 2 days to work on the scripts, but need the model in order to do so.

Any ideas how to restore the GPU-model on the CPU-only machine?

Error message on the CPU machine is:

```
Failed to get the number of CUDA devices: CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version
Floating point exception (core dumped)
```

Looking for a hack. Can I rename the tensornames to pretend they come from a CPU?

Comment: clear_devices=true, but your error suggests you would crash even with CPU only graph (GPU version of tf needs cuda on machine even if it's CPU only machine)

Comment: It does work with its own models, same script, just trained locally. Will try your hack. Looks like this tf.ConfigProto(clear_devices=true)?

Comment: Googled it. I need to SAVE the model with the cleared devices, right? Hmm, doesn't halp (or only a little)...

Comment: This seems to work with meta_graph saving and restoring, not with the tensors. Tried it and the keyword argument is unknown.

Comment: Note that your error though is unrelated to GPU device annotations in your graph (though that will be a problem too). Initializing of CUDA devices happens before the runtime looks at your graph

Comment: there are various places which support `clear_devices` flags, although possibly not all that need to. As a final work-around, you can open `.pbtxt` file in text editor, and delete all lines starting with `.device`

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov: Thanks! Setting clear_devices flags works for me. I'm leaving the SO link for further reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40451974/tensorflow-restore-variables-in-a-specific-device