# C++ equivalent of train.import_meta_graph clear_devices argument?

Tags: c++, machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm trying to train a graph on GPU using python, to load graph from C++ process.

```
status = ReadBinaryProto(Env::Default(), "model.pb", &graph_def);
session->Create(graph_def);
```

Then I got error message

"Cannot assign a device to node ... because no device matching that specification are registered in this process; available devices: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"

For python train.import_meta_graph API has clear_devices argument, but what is equivalent of it on C++ API?

For loading graph, I'm using Tensorflor on Windows built using CMake with -Dtensorflow_ENABLE_GPU=ON, so my vcxproj has GOOGLE_CUDA definition.

I've read [Tensorflow, restore variables in a specific device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40451974/tensorflow-restore-variables-in-a-specific-device) but it's only for python API.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you're exporting the graph from Python anyway, perhaps you can export a graph with the devices cleared out? Something like:

```
meta_graph = tf.train.export_meta_graph()
with tf.Graph().as_default():
    tf.train.import_meta_graph(meta_graph, clear_devices=True)
    # Export the GraphDef now
    with open('/tmp/model.pb', 'w') as f:
        f.write(tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().SerializeToString())
```

Alternatively, you could duplicate the behavior of `clear_devices=True` in C++ by clearing out the `device` field of every node in the graph. Something like:

```
status = ReadBinaryProto(Env::Default(), "model.pb", &graph_def);
for (int n = 0; n < graph_def.node_size(); ++n) {
  graph_def.mutable_node(n)->clear_device();
}
session->Create(graph_def);
```

But I would advise against that since it is relying on internal details of how `GraphDef`s are consumed by the framework, which might be fragile.

Comment: For I'm using train.Saver(), not export_meta_graph() on python, I cleared devices on C++, and Session::Create() succeeded using that graph! Thank you!